# Selenium: How to get plain text from html source?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, htmlunit

i'm going to rewrite all my tests project, by replacing Selenium by HtmlUnit because i'm not able to get plain text in selenium as i can do with htmlunit using "HtmlPage:asText" method. Getting plain text can help me to verify easily the content of a page, without  paying attention of the presence or not of the tags.

For example a plain text like this " One, two three" may correspond to many html source:

```
<p>One, two three</p>
```

or `<table> <tr><td>One1</td><td>two</td><td>three</td> </tr></table>`
or `<div><span>One, </span> <span>two, </span> <span>three, </span> </div>`

By using HtmlUnit i can write functional test without  paying attention of how the actual content will be represented in the html format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you only plain text in page

```
String pageSource=driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
```

Below logic will gives you entire page source.

```
driver.getPageSource();
```

Comment: python equivalent: `driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').text`